# [Javascript]- removeEvenlistner not working, what is wronge?

Tags: javascript

```
function circlediv(x,y,event)
{   
var par=document.getElementById('fine');    
var sull;
sull=document.createElement('div');
par.insertBefore(sull,par.firstChild);
sull.id='sullji';
sull.style.position='absolute';
sull.style.left=x+'px';
sull.style.top=y+'px';
sull.style.backgroundColor='black';
par.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){ dimer();},false);

}

function dimer()
{
sull=document.getElementById('sullji'); 
var l=sull.style.left.replace("px","");
var t=sull.style.top.replace("px","");
var w=event.pageX-Number(l); var h=event.pageY-Number(t);
sull.style.width=w+'px'; sull.style.height= h+'px';
}

function removeer()
{
var par2=document.getElementById('fine');   
par2.removeEventListener("mousemove",function(){ dimer();},false);
}
```

I am trying to remove the eventListner that i added to par element, but unable to do it. please help.
Thankx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you currently pass in the second argument to `.removeEventListener()` is not the same function that you added with `.addEventListener()`. Both functions do the same thing, but they are distinct from one another... You need to pass a reference to the *same* function, so don't use an anonymous function.

In fact in this case you don't actually need the anonymous function anyway, since the only thing it does is call the `dimer()` function, so:

```
par.addEventListener("mousemove", dimer, false);


par2.removeEventListener("mousemove", dimer, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
par.addEventListener("mousemove", dimer, false);

par2.removeEventListener("mousemove",dimer ,false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener